# Regular expression to match individual words in a phrase

Tags: c#, regex

I am using regular expressions for performing site search. 
If I search for this : "Villas at Millwood" (this is a community name) and the corresponding community name is "Villas at Millwood" , I get the results.

If I search for "Millwood villas" , there are no results populated.

I mean, the phrase is taken as a whole, and matched. Is there any way to match the any occurance of individual words in the entered phrase? so that "millwood Villas" would still bring the result of 
"Villas at Millwood" ?

Here is what I have to match the community name :

```
Regex.IsMatch(MarketingCommunityName.Trim(), pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

where pattern is the entered search phrase and the MarketingCommunityName is the actual community name.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you tried running multiple calls to `IsMatch` based on a `Split` of the pattern?

Comment: You could also search for Villas or Millwood, and check if the words nearby contain Villas or Millwood (depending on what you searched)

Comment: I tried that, but Ismatch is returning true only when both pattern and  community name exactly matches. Splitting both community name and pattern to individual words will not be good, because every community will have the word 'the' or 'a' or 'at' so matching it wont be appropriate. Moreover we have 1000 communities and each community name has atleast 5 words on it.

Comment: Split the pattern, search for every individual word. If you have a match, continue. If you don't have a match, abort and return false. If you get through all the matches, return true. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think that you should `Split` your search pattern at a space, and then check every word separately, it would not be too hard to construct an order-independent regular expression from your search pattern:

```
var searchWords = searchString.Trim().Split(new Char[] {' '});

string pattern = @"^(?=.*" + String.Join(@")(?=.*", searchWords) + ")";
```

This constructs a regex that contains one lookahead assertion per search word. Each lookahead assertion starts from the beginning of the string and looks whether the search word shows up anywhere inside the string. Note that you will likely get problems, if your `searchString` contains regex meta-characters, so these should probably be escaped beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

A regex pattern finding both patterns would be

```
\bMillwood\b.*\bvillas\b
```

where `\b` denotes the beginning or the end of a word and `.*` stands for any number of characters.

I you don't mind finding part of words, you can drop the `\b`'s

```
Millwood.*villas
```

However you would not find `"villas of Millwood"` for instance. This pattern would

```
Millwood.*villas|villas.*Millwood
```

But if you want to expand this serach to patterns consisting of more than three words Regex is not the right choice to implement this kind of fuzzy logic. I would count the number of distinct maching words and return the phrases yielding a minimum count. (Maybe having at least 60% of the given words.)

Answer (score 0):

Split the phrase and check every word

```
pattern.Split(' ')
    .All(word=>Regex.IsMatch(MarketingCommunityName.Trim(), word, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```